# Reading GRiB2 files with Matlab

Tags: matlab, grib

Are there any toolboxes, which allow reading GRIB2 data into Matlab?

An example (waves modeled by NOAA) could be GRIB2 available from ftp://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/history/waves

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [NCTOOLBOX for Matlab](http://nctoolbox.github.io/nctoolbox/), you can open a GRIB2 file just like a local NetCDF file or a remote OPeNDAP dataset:

```
% download data
! wget ftp://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/history/waves/multi_1.at_4m.dp.200607.grb2

% create ncgeodataset object
nc=ncgeodataset('multi_1.at_4m.dp.200607.grb2');

% list variables
nc.variables

% create geovariable object
dirvar=nc.geovariable('Primary_wave_direction_degree_true_surface');

% get data at 1st time step
dir=dirvar.data(1,:,:);

% get grid at 1st time step
g=dirvar.grid_interop(1,:,:);

% plot
pcolorjw(g.lon,g.lat,dir);
title(datestr(g.time))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Rich. Your answer is very helpful. I was also wondering how to plot the time series wave data (i.e wave height) at a given coordinate? Currently the WWIII model gives the wave data at each month, how to combine the time series wave plot of each month into a whole year time series? For example, I want to plot the wave height at a given location against time series for a entire year say 1998.

Comment: Much appreciated if you could help. Regards, Ian

Comment: Ian, you should ask this as a separate question

Comment: Thanks Rich! I got the same problem today in the morning and now have the answer.