# Reading GRiB Files in MatLab

Tags: matlab, grib

I'm currently trying to read atmospheric data from a GRiB file in MatLab, but I'm very foreign to controlling data like this. I've currently got nctoolbox downloaded and placed in my toolbox folder. Eventually I want to be able to pull select data out of this GRiB and manipulate it in vector fields, but I'm having trouble even reading in any lines of data.

Are there any good tutorials for using A) nctoolbox B) reading GRiB in MatLab or otherwise?

I've also got the matlab-cdi toolbox, but can't seem to get the commands correct to read in the files.

Would appreciate any and all help relating to this!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158222/reading-grib2-files-with-matlab?rq=1

Comment: I tried using this resource, but it didn't work for me. For instance, with the nc = ncgeodataset('gribfilename'); I came away with 

"Undefined function 'ncgeodataset' for input arguments of type 'char'."

Comment: That error shows that Matlab can't recognize the function and that probably means the nctoolbox is not properly installed. Do you run the `setup_nctoolbox.m` file every time you use nctoolbox? As suggested [here](http://nctoolbox.github.io/nctoolbox/)?

Comment: Mahm00d, I think you're right. I'm not sure if I ran setup_nctoolbox.m before having attempted to decode the gribv-1. Since then I have been using read_grib as it is a little more boob-friendly. I'll have to go back and try nctoolbox, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is use wgrib to convert data into binary file by following command.

```
system('wgrib %%gribfile%% -match \"%%variable name%%\" -no_header -bin temp.bin')
```

and then read the binary file in variable and then use reshape function to arrange it.