# Extracting data from GRIB file with Matlab

Tags: matlab, grib

I would like to extract wind data (speed and direction) from a GRIB file, as the one attached

Does anyone know a Matlab routine to do this operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading GRiB2 files with Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158222/reading-grib2-files-with-matlab)