# Downloading GRIB files directly into Matlab

Tags: matlab, url, download, grib

I want to read in data from the GFS weather forecasting model. The NOAA has some URL links from which the data can be downloaded, e.g.:

https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25_1hr.pl?file=gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f005&lev_surface=on&var_CAPE=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.2019053006

In the internet browser, this link automatically downloads a file (but which format?). In Matlab I do the following:

```matlab
fullURL = ['https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25_1hr.pl?file=gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f011&lev_surface=on&var_CAPE=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.2019053006'];

filename = 'cape_test.anl';

urlwrite(fullURL,filename);
```

These files open well in GIS software such as QGIS or ArcGIS. But how can I now read in these files automatically in MatLab so I can display them with the `imagesc()` command? Trying NCToolbox didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading GRiB2 files with Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158222/reading-grib2-files-with-matlab)

Comment: It's not. My post deals with .anl files.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you download the file first. Then build a script to look up directories inside a folder.

Could even source from the browser download folder.

```
% Directory

directory = 'C:\Datasets\NOAA\myfile';

%Do stuff
```

Comment: This is not the only file I need to download. My program considers different meteorological variables at all vertical levels of the atmosphere. It's very time consuming so I'd like to automate the process.

Comment: build a script to download the files using python then read the files with matlab

Comment: I think the best way to do it is having a folder with all the files and letting matlab loop through the data